# Styles, scripts and images in Area folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've setup an Admin area within MVC 3 application and while everything is working when I reference files from the root Scripts, Styles and Images folder, it doesn't work when I created those folders under `/Areas/admin/` and referenced them like this:

```
@Script.Include("~/admin/Scripts/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js")
```

Please note that this `Script.Include` helper is something that I have that essentially spits out this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/Scripts/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js"></script>
```

So the helper is working and everything is fine when I reference like this

```
@Script.Include("~/Scripts/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js")
```

but not when I introduce the area name in there. It results in a 404 Error.

Comment: additionally, the server issues 404 and the RouteDebugger show that no route was hit. Which is fine coz it shouldn't be but why is the server returning 404?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because the actual path to your script is the following:

```
@Script.Include("~/areas/admin/Scripts/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js")
```

which should render:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/areas/admin/Scripts/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js"></script>
```

Notice the `Areas` prefix that I added.

Comment: Any idea why I can't access scripts inside the Views folder. I want to put view specific scripts next to the cshtml file?

Comment: *Necromancy, if it helps anyone*
This is because of the separate web.config in the Views folder. It instructs IIS to block all file requests, but can be changed to allow specific types.